# multiple columns with multiple values in where clause

Tags: teradata

I am executing a query which has multiple columns in where clause which has multiple values. I know that in SQL you can use IN condition to satisfy and get the correct output. What is the way to do in teradata?

my code in Oracle looks like this:

```
select td.country_code,td.phone_num 
from telephone_directory td 
where (td.country_code, td.phone_num) in ((91,1234567890),(44,1020304050),(1,998877446655))
```

This prints out the exact result i.e. 3 rows

My query in teradata looks like this

```
select country_code ,phone_num  
from telephone_directory 
where (country_code in (91, 44, 1) and phone_num in( 1234567890, 1020304050, 998877446655)
```

This however returns more rows:

```
country_code  phone_num  
91            1234567890
91            1020304050
44            1020304050
1             998877446655
```

NOTE: The combination of country_code and phone num is not unique.

Is there a way to filter it out in teradata like that in ORACLE?

Comment: The top query uses a "pairwise comparison subquery" (source: 2007 Oracle SQL class slides). It means that the two values have to exist in the same row. The second query is a non-pairwise comparison and the two values can exist in different rows as each other. 

As Teradata cannot do pairwise comparisons, the best answer is probably the one below showing to concatenate the values into a combined key.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Teradata does not support the "expanded" where clause syntax as you can do in Oracle; you need to specify the criteria as compound expressions:

```
select country_code ,phone_num
from telephone_directory
where (country_code=91 and phone_num=1234567890)
   or (country_code=44 and phone_num=1020304050)
   or (country_code=1  and phone_num=998877446655)
```

Comment: Agreed - Teradata doesn't support the "expanded" WHERE clause syntax. +1

Answer (score 3):

```sql
select USER_TYPE,USER_ID
from USER_TABLE
where (USER_TYPE || USER_ID) in (('F6713'),('S1178'),('M5715'),('F8341'),('F1284'))
```

Comment: what? Where did you get those values?

Answer (score 2):

Logically the results from Teradata that you are seeing are correct. You have one phone number with multiple country codes. The following SQL should produce the result you are looking to see:

```
select td.country_code,td.phone_num 
from telephone_directory td 
where (td.country_code, td.phone_num) 
   in ( SELECT 91 AS country_code_
             , 1234567890 AS phone_num_
         UNION 
        SELECT 44 AS country_code_
             , 1020304050 as phone_num_
         UNION
        SELECT 1 as country_code_
             , 998877446655 as phone_num_
      );
```

This could also be re-written using the WITH clause or a combination of AND statements grouped together with parenthesis to produce the correct results.